It is possible to find $A,B \subset R$ such that $\sup A=\sup B$ and $A \cap B = \emptyset$?
It is possible to find $A,B \subset R$ such that $\sup A=\sup B$ and $A \cap B = \emptyset$ and $\sup A \not\in A$ and $\sup B\notin B$?
i think i can consider $S=\mathbb{Q} \cap (0,1)$ and $T=\mathbb{I} \cap (0,1)$ and then $S\cap T = \emptyset$ and $\sup A=1=\sup B$ but $1 \notin A,B$ am i right?

You're right, there is no need for the least upper bound be part of the sets.

What is $\mathbb I$ ?

@KurtG. I think irrational numbers

It suffices to restrict to  rational numbers. $$A=\left {-{1\over 2n}\right },\  B=\left {-{1\over 2n+1}\right }$$

Yes, another example is given by $A=\{-1/n: n\in\mathbb N\}$ and $B=\{-\sqrt{2}/n: n\in\mathbb N\}$. Clearly $\mathrm{sup}(A)=\mathrm{sup}(B)=0$ and $A\cap B=\emptyset$.
